# Centos 7 Sofia-sip dependency for Janus sip gateway

Tags: centos7, sip

I trying to install Janus WebRTC Gateway on Centos 7. But when I run

```
sudo yum install sofia-sip-devel
```

I have this message

```
No package sofia-sip-devel available.
```

I found this answer in Janus google group
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/meetecho-janus/dmJpJuWoSpw/RUcrr1sjEQAJ
But

```
wget ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/m/ma/magicspecs/apt/3.0/x86_64/RPMS.s/sofia-sip-1.12.11-6mgc30.x86_64.rpm
```

produces

```
No such directory ‘mirror/ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/m/ma/magicspecs/apt/3.0/x86_64/RPMS.s’.
```

So I guess there is some another repo link should be. Also I found this Docker
https://hub.docker.com/r/uangel/janus/~/dockerfile/

But when I try to follow it's commands I still get

```
SIP Gateway:           no
```

In plugin list when configure Janus.

So my question is how to make sofi-sip libriary visible for Janus configure to install Janus SIP Gateway plugin? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems the pre-built packages are gone. You'll have to build it yourself. That's generally straightforward with

```
./configure
make
make install
```

It's usually a good idea to add a prefix like `--prefix=/usr/local/sofia-sip`to ./configure, but then you'd have to add the path to sofia when configuring **janus** like this:

```
LDFLAGS='-L/home/foo/sw/lib/' ./configure <any other parameters>
```

You can get the sources for sofia-sip at http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=143636

### UPDATE:

Adding a file named `config.site` with the following content did it for me:

```
CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/sofia-sip/include
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/sofia-sip/lib
```

Comment: I installed sofia-sip with this commands
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/sofia-sip
make
make install
But when I run 
LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/sofia-sip' ./configure --prefix=/opt/janus
still no success((

Comment: Forgot about CPPFLAGS. Couldn't try this on CentOS, but it worked fine on arch.

Answer (score 0):

There is no RPM for CentOS 7 right now. But you can download the [src.rpm](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/rpmphp/zoom.php?rpm=sofia-sip) for Fedora and rebuild it.
However, this is probably not as straightforward as you'd probably like.